# Angular 7.1.3 : post not work with Authorization Bearer token

Tags: angular, angular7

I am new to Angular and I am using Angular 7.1.3
I successfully Logged to my Laravel 5.7 Passport API system by Angular HTTP and get access token and store in cookies.

Now I want to Simply get data using Access token but I can not get data it gives 302 redirection error :

My Code is for auth.service.ts is :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
import { GlobalvarsService } from "./globalvars.service";
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient, private globvar : GlobalvarsService, private router : Router) { }

details(){

      const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content':'application/json',
              'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+  Cookie.get('access_token')
          }),
      };

      let input = new FormData();
      this.http.get(mypath + 'api/details',httpOptions).subscribe(
          data => {
              console.log('dddddddd');
                console.log(data);

          },
          error => {
          }
      )
  }
```

Note: `mypath` is my URL

what is wrong with my code? there is not set `POST` method it set `OPTIONS` when sending the request.

Comment: Read about CORS and preflight

Comment: I have test same with POSTMEN and its works

Comment: Besides, I see no `POST` here only `GET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called preflight request and is enforced by the browser due to Cross Origin Resource Sharing - CORS in short - policy. You have no direct control over it.

Preflight request is made to the server to "ask" if it is ok to perform required request. It is done when request you try to make is considered "not simple". On what that means you can see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests

So this is expected behavior in some circumstances. If you make requests to the same domain that application resides, no preflights will be made. If you make non simple requests to foreighn resources, CORS applies and 'question' will be asked. From application point of view, you can only change your requests to be simple if you don't want preflights.

To the base, what stink  in that code:

1. You set `Content-Type` on `GET` request. Why? `GET` has no content, so no type
2. `Content` header is probably considered CUSTOM and that causes the preflight to happen. I only assume you wanted `Accept` header to indicate that you want response to be `json`
3. If you have your auth token in cookies, why sending it with header? You will end up with request that has the same data twice - in cookies and in headers.
4. Normally attaching authorization data to request is done with http interceptors so it is done to every request without of need of adding those by hand to every request (like you try to do) https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses